# how can I configure an activemq queue to make it not accepting messages?

Tags: configuration, activemq-classic

I am an activeMQ newbie. Is it possible to add something to the activeMQ xml configuration to force a queue to stop accepting messages when (for example) 100 messages are already in a specific queue?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ expose the queue size with JMX, so i guess you can use that information to limit the queue size.
see: [Queue size thread](http://www.apacheserver.net/Resolved-AMQ-2676-Exception-sending-to-an-ActiveMQ-queue-from-at214918.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Producer Flow Control http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html

It limits your queue on the amount of memory the queue takes

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, you may want to consider configuring a pending message limit strategy or a message eviction policy:

http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

These two options are mainly for use in a slow consumer situation to work with the consumer's prefetch buffer. But I'm suggesting them to you because I don't understand the full context of your question or know your requirements.

Bruce